# Oneliner to load Lua script from online (Gist) and run in current context

Tags: lua, download, eval, read-eval-print-loop

I have a lua REPL, and would like to run a lua script file stored as plain text at `HTTPS://URL`. I understand `os.execute()` can run OS commands so we can use `curl` etc. to grab the script then `load()`. Is that something possible to do in lua REPL with a single line?

Comment: `(loadstring or load)(io.popen("wget -qO- http://i.imgur.com/91HtaFp.gif"):read"*a")()` - this program will print "Hello world"

Comment: It is not obvious to me what this program is doing. I see it is running wget for a gif and loading that gif as a code, and somehow magically do hello world?

Comment: Also, when I try to run it in my REPL, it fails: input:1: attempt to call a nil value (field 'popen'). Maybe my REPL is restricted? It is part of a larger program, as a embedded module. Also `io.open` and `io.stdout` seems to work.

Comment: Also `io.open` and `io.stdout` seems to work. In my `io` table, there is no `exec` or `popen`. So I cannot do it?

Comment: You can invoke OS command only if you have `os.execute()` or `io.popen()`.  Some Lua environments restrict access to OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** If you're going to run source code directly from the web, use `https` at least, to avoid easy MitM attacks.

To give this question an answer, since Egor will probably not post it as such:

```
(loadstring or load)(io.popen("wget -qO- https://i.imgur.com/91HtaFp.gif"):read"*a")()
```

For why this prints `Hello world`:

`loadstring or load` is to be compatible with different Lua versions, as the functions `loadstring` and `load` were merged at some point (5.2 I believe). `io.popen` executes its first argument in the shell and returns a file pointer to its stdout.

The "gif" from Egor is not really a GIF (open this in your browser: `view-source:https://i.imgur.com/91HtaFp.gif`) but a plain text file that contains this text:

```
GIF89a=GIF89a
print'Hello world'
```

Basically a GIF starts with `GIF89a` and the `=GIF89a` afterwards is just to produce valid Lua, meaning you don't have to use imgur or gifs, you can just as well use raw gists or github.

Now, it's rather unlikely that `os.execute` is available in a sandbox when `io.popen` is not, but if it is, you can achieve a one-liner (though drastically longer) using `os.execute` and temporary files

Lets first write this out because in a single line it will be a bit complex:

```lua
(function(u,f)
    -- get a temp file name, Windows prefixes those with a \, so remove that
    f=f or os.tmpname():gsub('^\\','')
    -- run curl, make it output into our temp file
    os.execute(('curl -s "%s" -o "%s"'):format(u,f))
    -- load/run temp file
    loadfile(f)()
    os.remove(f)
end)("https://i.imgur.com/91HtaFp.gif");
```

And you can easily condense that into a single line by removing comments, tabs and newlines:

```lua
(function(u,f)f=f or os.tmpname():gsub('^\\','')os.execute(('curl -s "%s" -o "%s"'):format(u,f))loadfile(f)()os.remove(f)end)("https://i.imgur.com/91HtaFp.gif");
```

Comment: But in a sandbox it is impossible?

Comment: @hyiltiz If the sandbox allows neither `os.execute` nor `io.popen`, then you obviously can't go that route. Maybe it supports other options, like sockets or simply its own API to open http connections, but we can't tell you that on SO unless it's a public implementation and you tell us which it is

Comment: @dualed - Why "community wiki"? Don't be shy. You've done a great job, your answer is excellent.  You should get earned rep points.

Comment: Yours as well, I don't see you posting it ;) Anyway I mostly wrote it to explain your solution, which I found very clever (even though I had to rib you for using http), so I thought it would be weird to post it "as me".